# Is it possible to know what processes are running on a symbian phone with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, nokia

I know its possible with Symbian C++

as the following code

```
void GetProcessListL(void)
{
TFullName res;
TFindProcess find;
while(find.Next(res) == KErrNone)
{
    RProcess ph;
    ph.Open(find);

    // here you can use 
    // functions of the RProcess
    // to get more information
    // of the selected process.

    // res will have the process name..

    ph.Close();
}
}
```

However, is there a way to do this using only Qt?

As Symbian C++ is apparently obsolete, even Nokia does not recommend using it anymore.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a post on [Qt Centre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31555-Obtaining-list-of-running-processes-with-Qt-on-a-smartphone?p=147481#post147481) last year:

> > What Qt APIs will I need to get the
> >     processes for the QStringList?
>
> Getting
>   a string list will have to be done in
>   native way, so I can't help you there.

Here's an article on Nokia Developer about [Using Qt and Symbian C++ Together](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_Qt_and_Symbian_C++_Together?ticket=ST-48286-AOLNOrRjatdiVcWy7m4iT0TH59H0QO2bPUe-20) using the PIMPL pattern, it shows how to call native Symbian C++ from Qt code. This would of course have to be ported if you want to run it on other platforms.